# How to save logs from remote clients to a different file?

Tags: rsyslog

I have the below changes in the rsyslog.conf

```
#################
#### MODULES ####
#################

$ModLoad imuxsock # provides support for local system logging
$ModLoad imklog   # provides kernel logging support
#$ModLoad immark  # provides --MARK-- message capability
$Ruleset remote
*.* -/var/log/remote.log
$Ruleset RSYSLOG_DefaultRuleset
# provides UDP syslog reception
$ModLoad imudp
$InputUDPServerBindRuleset remote
$UDPServerRun 514
```

I have then restarted my rsyslogd.But it is not creating  remote.log file.As far as I know it is dynamic creating takes place.Neither it logs from remote clients even I have made remote.log with root permissions.all logs go to /var/log/syslog